# Need a simple accelerometer visualization example!

Tags: accelerometer, processing-lang

I'm doing a project using the ADXL335 accelerometer from SparkFun. The actual project I'm using P5 and it's working great. I'm running workshops in parallel and want to demo the chip in real-time but am currently out of time to build something from scratch. I'm desperate for a simple processing (or something else) sketch that takes my x, y, z values being printed to the serial port from Arduino and visualizes them in some way. Can anyone point me to anything that won't need a lot of coding time and effort just now?

Thank you!
Claudia

Comment: After some quick searching I found an [Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Using-an-Arduino-and-Python-to-plotsave-data/?ALLSTEPS) which uses your same sensor and plots the data thanks to a Python script. You'll need to install Python if you want to replicate this project, but any programming language with a drawing library will work.

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/ahrs-for-adafruits-9-dof-10-dof-breakout/visualizing-data

Comment: Here's my Python implementation.
It's desined for AOK-D but can be easily converted to work with external sensor
[IMU+AHRS](https://github.com/pedrodparkes/Luxonis-IMU-Visualization/blob/master/3D_Cube_AHRS/README.md)

Answer (score -1):

A simple and fast solution would be implement a chart using a JavaScript library called Chart.js. it is simple and you can visualize your data in realtime.

Try node.js to make the back-end by communicating via serial (serialport package is good) and send the data using socket.io.

It is simple and you can set everything in less than 2 hours.

[Chart.js](http://Chart.js)

I recently made some video tutorials about this and you see them [here](https://youtu.be/LNtmLapUSzw). The audio is in Portuguese but you can just skip and go directly to coding sections.

Comment: All great answers - thanks for each of them!! A processing forum user provided me with a processing script that worked great for my purposes. You can view the thread here:http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/comment/40648